# How to compare date() in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

In mysql date is formated as yyyy-mm-dd. I would to retrieve all related posts that is more then 25 days old.

Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE writtenday >= 25;
```

Many thanks

Comment: Is your date stored as string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM post WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), writtenday) >= 25;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`DATE_SUB`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub) function

```
WHERE writtenday <= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 25 DAY)
```

This will retrieve anything that is older than TODAY-25 Days